# How to run Uiautomator tests in to multiple devices?

Tags: android-testing, android-uiautomator, gradle-android-test-plugi

I am trying to Uiautomator android Ui tests in a .bat file. but i could not able them run parallelly.

Here is my execution flow and have connected 3 devices

-> `adb devices XXXX XXXX XXXX`

-> `adb push ./bin/UiautomatorTests.jar /data/local/tmp/`

-> `adb shell uiautomator runtest UiautomatorTests.jar -c com.music.tests`

Here how can i give a common common command for all the devices to runs with parllely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout [Uiautomator-bot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/) as it seems to fit your requirement. It can run UIautomator test cases simultaneously on all connected devices.
For further info check this [link](http://uiautomator-bot.blogspot.in/).

Comment: Thanks for the Tool. I think this is for only Linux machine. But i need it on Windows.

Comment: I am working on windows version will be available asap.

Comment: Windows version of Uiautomator-bot is released.

Comment: What about a version of OSX?  Would that be possible?

Comment: will be available by this weekend.

Answer (score 3):

You can well use

```
adb -s <device_id> push ./bin/UiautomatorTests.jar /data/local/tmp/
adb -s <device_id> shell uiautomator runtest UiautomatorTests.jar -c com.music.tests
```

Using above commands, you can run 3 parallel instances of your automation changing `<device id>` appropriately

You can find your `<device id>` from `adb devices`

Good luck !!

Comment: This can be done.But here the problem, Device ID has to enter manually and run the test cases. Is there any way where device ID can take automatically and run across the devices ?

Comment: Yes you can write a script to capture adb devices output, grep the device id and give out the command.. it should be possible with perl..