# uiautomator runs multiple tests on multiple devices?

Tags: ui-automation

My requirement is :

I Have a two methods and two mobiles... Q1::: i want to run first method in first mobile and second method in second mobile parllely. Q2::: two methods in two mobiles parllelly, Thanx in advance,please help me..

am running from "run.sh"

```
/home/rakesh/Android_sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create uitest-project -n LaunchSettings -t 1 -p /home/rakesh/tests

export ANDROID_HOME='/home/rakesh/Android_sdk/android-sdk-linux'

ant build

adb push /home/rakesh/tests/bin/LaunchSettings.jar /data/local/tmp/

adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.smartron.test.LaunchSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these following questions for clear picture about what can be done with UIautomator.

1. [Automating call scenario with Uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225178/how-to-script-mo-call-and-browsing-on-2-devices-from-uiautomator-for-android-dev/27226161#27226161)
2. [How to run Uiautomator tests in to multiple devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301292/how-to-run-uiautomator-tests-in-to-multiple-devices/25469010#25469010)